# How can I keep a specific variable name after JavaScript minification performed by Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, minify, hotjar

I want one variable name to be kept after my code is minified. Not sure if this matters, but it also has to survive TypeScript being compiled to minified JavaScript.

Details:

- I'm using Angular CLI and when I use the console command `ng build --prod` all my TypeScript is converted to a single minified JavaScript file.
- I'm using [Mouseflow](https://mouseflow.com) and want to implement ["Combining Several Pages in One Heatmap"](https://web.archive.org/web/20190321120959/http://help.mouseflow.com/knowledge_base/topics/combine-several-pages-in-one-heatmap) as described on that Mouseflow knowledge base page.
- When I add a variable as described and do a production build, my variable gets a new name so Mouseflow is unable to reference the variable in parent scope by name.

Here's the related info from the mouseflow knowledge base:

> If you add the `mouseflowPath` variable and set it to `var mouseflowPath = '/shop/products/productdetail;'` on these pages, Mouseflow will treat all of these pages as one unique page and only generate one heatmap under the URL `'/shop/products/productdetail'`.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     window._mfq = window._mfq || [];
>
>     // *** THIS NEEDS TO STAY ***
>     var mouseflowPath = '/shop/products/productdetail';
>
>     (function() {
>         var mf = document.createElement("script"); mf.type = "text/javascript"; mf.async = true;
>         mf.src = "//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/your-website-id.js";
>         document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
>     })();
> </script>
> ```

The only clear solution that comes to mind is forcing the `mouseflowPath` variable to hold its original name through minification.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than this:

```
var mouseflowPath = '/your/new/path';
```

use this:

```
window['mouseflowPath'] = '/your/new/path';
```

---

Both results are precisely the same. Using property accessor syntax above will allow the string, and your global reference, to be preserved.

Comment: [Clever](https://media1.tenor.com/images/4e9618e091345ca9d07955d60b511b49/tenor.gif?itemid=9559854). @Methodician -- I think that solved your problem, didn't it? Did you find a better answer?